# My query is running in php myadmin withing few seconds and getting time exceeds in code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Following are the query which is executed:

```
select esd.voucher_id, esd.qty,esd.rate,esd.str_percentage,esd.cur_inr, v.voucher_date, v.bill_no, v.currency,dbk.p_voucher_id,v.voucher_type, v.bill_pass_amt as amount_fc, v.exc_rate, v.amount_inr, v.payment_voucher,dbk.p_voucher_id,pre.inviceno,(select sum(amount) from rkisexport.preshipmentindex where inviceno=v.bill_no) as Total,intable.voucher_id as invoucher_id,intable.voucher_date as invoucher_date,intable.amount_inr as  stramt,intable.p_voucher_id as inpayment_voucher,intable.amt_settled_inr as amt_inr,intable.cheque_no,intable.ctdate,intable.cheque_tt,intable.tt_no,bdatetab.voucher_date as brvoucher_date from export_sales_details esd 
    join voucher v on esd.voucher_id = v.voucher_id
    left join dbk_str_received dbk on v.voucher_id = dbk.voucher_id
    left join preshipmentindex pre on pre.inviceno = v.bill_no
    left join (select vo.voucher_id,vo.bill_no,vo.voucher_settled,vo.voucher_date,vjo.amount_inr,vpd.p_voucher_id,vp.tt_no,vp.cheque_tt,vp.cheque_no,vp.ctdate,IFNULL((select sum(received) from dbk_str_received where p_voucher_id in(select voucher_id from voucher where voucher_date <= '".$to."' and voucher_id in(select p_voucher_id from dbk_str_received where voucher_id=vo.voucher_id  and type = '6456')) and voucher_id=vo.voucher_id and type='6456'),0) as amt_settled_inr from voucher vo join voucher_journal vjo on vjo.voucher_id=vo.voucher_id left join dbk_str_received vpd on vpd.voucher_id=vo.voucher_id left join voucher_payment_detail vp on vp.voucher_id=vpd.p_voucher_id where vo.voucher_type='IN' and vjo.account_code='6456') intable on intable.bill_no=v.bill_no
    left join (select voucher_date,voucher_id from voucher) bdatetab on bdatetab.voucher_id=intable.p_voucher_id
    where esd.str_applicable =1 and v.voucher_type = 'ES' and v.company_id in ( 'RKR' ) and v.voucher_date >= '".$from."' and v.voucher_date <= '".$to."'  group by esd.voucher_id order by ".$sortBy."
```

Comment: what a format bro !

Comment: Have you try with this ? ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); 
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing the data structure of your table. This query could be using too many resources or it's timing out during the execution.

In PHPMyAdmin access the PHP.ini file under the PHPMyAdmin control panel at PHP > php.ini.

Look for the following:

```
max_execution_time
memory_limit
```

These two things if increased may solve your issue. If that doesn't work you may have to change your codeigniter PHP.ini file as well for the settings above.

Comment: Thank you but it is executing within 15 seconds in php myadmin. php.ini can be the only reason?

Comment: Potentially you may need to change your .ini file in codeigniter to match the settings in phpmyadmin.